# cakephp2 HABT relational data can not retrieve

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have two Models, Doctor and Patient. I have related them each other through HABT.

I want to retrieve associated data of patients from model Doctor.ie I want to retrieve all patients belongs to a specific Doctor in DoctorsController.

I have following code in my DoctorController for index action.

```
$this->set('doctor_profile',$this->Doctor->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Doctor.'.$this->Doctor->primaryKey =>$this->Auth->user('id')))));
```

Its working perfectly in 'view' action in same controller but not in 'index' action. I'm looking to display data in index.ctp view of Doctor Controller

I have used this to display in index.ctp but it not working

```
echo "Doctor: ".$doctor_profile['Doctor']['username'];

echo "Patients :-";

foreach ($doctor_profile['Patience'] as $patience){

echo $patience['id']; 

echo $patience['name'];
}
```

the '$doctor_profile['Patience']' doesn't return any value. Shouldn't it be returning its related data Patience Model?

Solved by adding

```
$this->Doctor->recursive = 1;
```

Comment: It is looking okay. Make sure this doctor has patients . Thanks

Comment: yes I checked.There is patients for doctor.

Comment: can you please debug $doctor_profile ?

Comment: sry.I forgot to change recursive to 1.Thanks for your help Ansari.

Comment: I was thinking same. Why dont you use containable behaviour ? Glad to see that you have solved the issue yourself

Comment: I'm actually new to cake php.I'm aware of containable behaviour but dont know in detail.This is my first cake php project btw :)

Comment: I will use containable behaviour as am going through cake documentation on it.Thank again.